# Image processing - Why is sum of values of a blurring filter = 1?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, matrix

Usually, blurring filters have the sum of all the values in the filter matrix equal to $1$.

Why is it so?

Comment: The question contradicts the example, if the matrix that is provided is supposed to be a 3x3 convolution matrix. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Blurring an image means reducing its high frequencies while retaining the rest. Usually it's done with a low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of $\omega_c$. A standard low-pass filter would have a DC response of $1$; i.e., $$H(0,0) = 1$$

This translates into samples through the DTFT as:
$$ H(0,0) = \sum_n \sum_m h[n,m]e^{-j0n}e^{-j0n}  =\sum_n \sum_m h[n,m] = 1 $$

Which indicates that the sum of the impulse response samples is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

For constant images to remain constant after blurring.

The most blurred images are flat-valued with any constant $c$. They are left invariant by traditional smoothers, low-pass or blur filters, hence $\sum h_{k,l}c=c$, for all $c\neq 0$ when $\sum h_{k,l}=1$,